# Spring data jpa create field with Unix time format

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create an field that hold Unix time epoch format inside my entity.

```
    @Column(name="createdDate", updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @Column(name="updatedDate")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedDate;

    @Column(name="expirationDate")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp expirationDate;
```

I have managed to make it automatically inserted while inserted/updated to the DB, But it's inserted the `Date` format in stand of Unix time format for example: `1644887031`.

The actual value that is inserted it this:

```
"createdDate": "2022-02-15T00:56:38.667+00:00",
"updatedDate": "2022-02-15T00:56:38.667+00:00",
"expirationDate": "2022-02-15T00:56:38.667+00:00"
```

How can I modify to Unix time format?

Thanks!

Comment: *How can I modify to Unix time format?* - why would you want to?

Comment: I'm creating an Restful API, my client know how to translate the timestamp to the needed format..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` for datatype and try as follows.

```
@Column(name="createdDate", updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdDate;

@Column(name="updatedDate")
@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedDate;

@Column(name="expirationDate")
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date expirationDate;
```

Comment: `Date` is belong to `sql` or `util`?

Comment: `java.util.Date`

Comment: It's still showing the same way..

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to solve it by adding custom `Getter` method which return a timestamp.

```
public long getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate.getTime();
}
```